Dereferencing a Local Reference to a Global Struct Member vs. Memcpy’ing
I have a callee function invoked by a caller function that modifies the contents of a member of a field in a union. This union is nested within a strut, and the struct is globally scoped. However, the reference to this particular field is syntactically long, so I declare a local pointer to this field within the caller function to lessen the verbosity of the function call. The union encapsulated within the struct, and the struct itself are structured like this:
typedef union
{
    uint8_t data[8];
    struct 
    {
        uint32_t data_u32;
    } PARAM_U32;

    struct
    {
        float data_f;
    } PARAM_FLOAT;

 } EXAMPLE_UNION;

typedef struct
{
    EXAMPLE_UNION member1;
    EXAMPLE_UNION member2;
} EXAMPLE_STRUCT;

EXAMPLE_STRUCT global_example_struct;

void callee_func(uint32_t *pDataToModify, uint32_t newVal)
{
    *pDataToModify = newVal;
}

void caller_func()
{

    uint32_t *pMemberOfNestedUnionToModify = (uint32_t *)&EXAMPLE_STRUCT.member1.PARAM_U32.data_u32

    uint32_t dummyNewVal = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    
    callee_func(pMemberOfNestedUnionToModify, dummyNewVal);
}

When the callee_func() directly attempts to dereference the pointer passed in as an argument, a hard fault occurs. This confuses me, as although it is a local reference, it references globally scoped data. However, when the callee_func() instead only copies memory to the pointer, the operation is successful and the field is updated:
void callee_func(uint32_t *pDataToModify, uint32_t newVal)
{
    // this works
    memcpy((uint8_t *)pDataToModify, (uint8_t *)&newVal, 4);
}

Why is it invalid to dereference the local pointer passed in an argument, but valid to copy data to it? Is it because the local reference is just a reference, and merely points to the instance of the globally scoped data, and therefore has no stack space allocated to actually store a value?

EXAMPLE_STRUCT is a type name, not an object, so the code … &EXAMPLE_STRUCT.member1.PARAM_U32.data_u32 will yield a compiler message, not a “hard fault,” if, by that, you mean a segment fault or similar run-time error. That suggests this code is not the actual code that failed but something you have prepared in its place but not faithfully reproduced the error. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Quite likely, there is some other error in your program, not this.

And that problem should be the same whether you dereference or use memcpy. The only difference between the two ways of writing the value is whether padding bytes are copied.

BTW, you shouldn't hard-code the length 4. Use sizeof (uint32_t)

OT: If you have a variable (or member of a structure) of type uint32_t, and use the pointer-to operator & to get a pointer to that variable, the result will have the type uint32_t *. Doing an explicit conversion (a cast) to the same type have no meaning.

OT: All upper-case names are commonly used for macros, not types or variables or structure/union members.

After replacing &EXAMPLE_STRUCT.member1.PARAM_U32.data_u32 with &global_example_struct.member1.PARAM_U32.data_u32, fixing minor syntax errors and converting caller_func to main, the code runs without error, and the result is as expected. see https://onlinegdb.com/QpYLUgtB-

Search for "Law of Demeter".  It is more usually applied to OO languages (C++, Java, etc), but the concept applies to C, too, with appropriate changes.  Basically, if you need to access 4 levels deep in a structure, you should wonder if you've got the data encapsulated appropriately.  It's extra problematic if you have pointers in the references: ptr->another->third->member has lots of opportunities for null pointers, which might be a problem.


When the callee_func() directly attempts to dereference the pointer
passed in as an argument, a hard fault occurs. This confuses me, as
although it is a local reference, it references globally scoped data.
However, when the callee_func() instead only copies memory to the
pointer, the operation is successful and the field is updated

The answer is very easy:

memcpy can copy unaligned data.

Pointer punning can access the unaligned data and invoke hardware fault on targets which do not support unalighned accesses.


In the Cortex-M world:

Cortex-M0,M0+  - cannot access unaligned data
Cortex-M23 - cannot access unaligned data
Coterx-M7, M4, M3 & M33 - can access unaligned data

PS Remember that pointer punning may also violate strict aliasing rules invoking Undefined Behaviour.
Exmaple:
https://godbolt.org/z/fEW1hv8dz
As you can see when you pointers to pun types - the compiler assumes aligned accesss. On M23 target foo will HF if ptr or ptr1 are not 4 bytes aligned.

Since the address is for a member of the type being assigned, it's guaranteed to be properly aligned. So I don't see how any of this is relevant.

@Barmar I just see the effect - HF when is pointer punned - and no HF when it is memcpy-ied and I know well what is causing it.  So all your deliberations are invalid especially because the code you see is not the code which causes the HF only some OPs "pseudo code"

Since the code as posted shouldn't even compile, it's not really clear what the actual effect is.

@Barmar he wrote that the real code causes HF when pointer punned and no HF when memcopy-ied. The answer why is quite obvious I do not understand the DV

I didn't DV, so don't ask me.

It's not even clear what "hard fault" means. Segmentation fault, bus error (that's the usual fault for unaligned access), something else?

@Barmar ARM uses this term https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0646/c/The-Cortex-M7-Processor/Fault-handling/Fault-escalation-and-hard-faults
